# Delete both product table and product image table by join query

Tags: mysql

I have used this

```
 DELETE p.* , pm.* FROM product p  , productimage pm
 WHERE p.p_id = '1' and pm.p_id = '1';
```

but no results

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
      `p_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `p_names` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `p_price` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `p_description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productimage` (
      `pimage_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `img` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `p_id` int(10) NOT NULL,----------------------------foreign Key 
      PRIMARY KEY (`pimage_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE p, pm 
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN productimage pm ON p.p_id = pm.p_id
WHERE p.p_id = 1
```